# Assert a value type is the same at both sides of the assignment

Tags: typescript

Given this code in Typescript:

```js
interface InterfaceA {
  transfer?: string[];
  deposit?: number[];
  test?: boolean[];
}

interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA {
  moretest?: boolean[];
}

type Label = ("transfer" | "deposit" | "test")

const a: InterfaceA = {}
const b: InterfaceB = {}

const labels: Label[] = ["transfer" , "deposit" , "test"];

for (const label of labels){
    a[label] = b[label]
}
```

You get the error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

It fails to compile because `a[label]` (left side of the assignment) can be one of `string[]`, `number[]` or `test[]` while `b[label]` (right side of the assignment) can also be one of `string[]`, `number[]` or `test[]`.

It kinds of make sense, **except** that Typescript should know that if the left side is `string[]`, the right side will be `string[]` too, same applies for the other types.

This is why replacing the assignment with `a[label as "transfer"] = b[label as "transfer"]` works.

Now, what should I change in order to make it work without having to hardcode the typecasted value?

Other <strike>viable</strike> options which I don't like:

```js
a[label] = b[label] as any
```

```js
if (label == "transfer") {
    a[label] = b[label]
} else if (label == "deposit") {
    a[label] = b[label]
} else {
    a[label] = b[label]
}
```

Comment: ...After you do that, The main issue you're running into is that TypeScript can't deal with "correlated union" types, as described in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  If you want a single block of code like `a[label] = b[label]` to work for all `label` cases, you will need to refactor so that the type is *generic* and not a union.  In general such refactoring is described in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), but in your case it's easy enough to do directly with a generic callback as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/mL8Rvm).

Comment: ...Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYeYdW) is the code for the new version, let me know if you want an answer for it

Comment: @jcalz, thanks! That was exactly the kind of response I was looking for. Please add it  as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript can't handle "correlated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)" types in which a single block of code is checked multiple types for each member of a union.  This issue is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

From a pure type system perspective, it's unsafe, because the type of `b[label]` is the `InterfaceB[Label]` union, and the compiler is worried that when you try to assign it to `a[label]` of union type `InterfaceA[Label]`, maybe the two keys are actually different?  That is, it's ignoring the *identity* of `label` and just looking at the type.  Put another way: imagine you had `label1` and `label2` both of type `Label`.  Then `a[label1] = b[label2]` would clearly be unsafe. (See [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) for the pull request implementing this safety check.) Of course you're not doing this, but the compiler is unable to see the difference because the types are the same for both situations.

Of course you could fix it by writing `a[label] = b[label]` once for each narrowing of `label`, but that's not what you want to do.  You want a single block of code to be checked for multiple cases.

---

If you need a single block of code to be checked for multiple cases, you'll have to refactor to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of unions.  This can often be tricky, and in general requires some significant changes to the types involved, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  In your case, though, it's easy enough to iterate the array and use a generic callback function, like this:

```
labels.forEach(<K extends Label>(label: K) => {
    a[label] = b[label];
});
```

That works because the label is generic `K`, and the compiler is able to relate `InterfaceA[K]` to `InterfaceB[K]` in a way that it can't for `InterfaceA[Label]` and `InterfaceB[Label]`.

---

That code uses the [array `forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) because it's much easier to use  a callback there. You could have done it in a loop like

```
const cb = <K extends Label>(label: K) => { a[label] = b[label] };
for (const label of labels) {
    cb(label);
}
```

or even

```
for (const label of labels) {
    (<K extends Label>(label: K) => { a[label] = b[label] })(label);
}
```

but `forEach()` is more idiomatic.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJBBZBvAWAChlTkwo4QBnGaAfgC5lqLQBzAbQF0BuYssgAmEAA4B7asDBNkIAK4BbAEbQe-EmUitZy8eIA2EKuuIBfYsVCRYiFOhtYIAIWQQAHpBBDqaDLZx8ATJFcSgIbRlmPUNjEFMiCyJiMABPURQAGThVA2QAXmQACgAiCipaaBLkAB9kEpEJKTBqurKIVhKASksiBHEaMGQ4ZgdMO1xCvCT+weRlUf8nVymk4lnWZAMciANqZmzcngLkTjLKGjooEoAaesbJaVv6yJK+Xu3c6gA6GDCAUUQAAsigAeADSbk8EG8vkOuwAfEVPrtmOCugUEUFNKQ4JwUQZuCdlPidoSNGYuhp1gNNghlCcIVCvD5kPCDEiCWiMfksXhhqTckTCiSCUSzBo-lBihshgTkOIYFsydQMYQcch6ciyVTzL0pTLaXKyQqlQTVdjBGDIR4WXCyZyydzMfgBWLiYLduKutrcrrEkA)

Comment: Great answer! I appreciate the alternatives to `forEach()` as in my case I needed to await some async functions and it can be troublesome using `forEach()`