# TypeScript error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' when using bracket notation

Tags: typescript

Here is a snippet that is supposed to represent a minimal reproducible piece of code:

```
type Person ={
  name:string
  age:number
}

type Message = {
  src: keyof Person
  value: string
}

const person:Person = {
  name:"John",
  age:30,
}

const msg:Message ={
  src:"name",
  value:"Bob"
}

person[msg.src] = msg.value; // Here I get the error:  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I get the following error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Why is there an error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Curiously, if you set `msg.src = "name"` before the last line, the error goes away.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't know what the key is exactly, so it uses the intersection of the types that the possible keys produce. In this case, the intersection of `Person["name"]` and `Person["age"]` is `string & number`, which resolved to `never`.

Comment: Yes the problem is I cant because the `msg.src` in my case is determined by the name of the <input> and the `msg.value` would be `e.target.value` whick means I dont know from which exactly input the message woud come. I know the list of possible values `msg.src` but not which one exactly

Comment: Also, your `msg.value` is always a string, so it wouldn't be assignable to `person.age`.

Comment: Ohh thats it @DarrylNoakes
`Person["age"] is string & number,` 
Thanks. Make it answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

The issue is that TypeScript doesn't know *which* key `msg.src` is going to be, and therefore doesn't know which type is to be assigned to. Because of this, TS finds the *common type* of all the possible types, which is the intersection of those types.

Your key could be any key of `Person`, so the result is this:

```js
type t1 = Person["name"] & Person["age"]
//   ^? never

// Person["name"] & Person["age"]
// = string & number
// = never
```

This is what produces the error you saw: the only possible type is `never`, and nothing is assignable to `never`.

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4bxaN)

---

Additional note:

The `value` property of your `Message` type is a `string`, yet you allow the key a message applies to to be either `name` or `age`; because `age` is a `number`, this is an issue, as you could never actually update the age.
The solution fixes this as well.

### Solution, Part 1

To properly type what you are doing, you first of all need to have properly distinguished keys, and link the key you are operating on to the type of that key in the destination object. To do this, you can create a **discriminated union** ([official TypeScript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/discriminate-types), [Demystifying TypeScript Discriminated Unions - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/typescript-discriminated-unions/)) based on the keys.

```js
type Message = {
  [key in keyof Person]: { src: key; value: Person[key] }
}[keyof Person]

const msg: Message = {
  src: "name",
  value: "Bob",
}

person[msg.src] = msg.value // No error (yet)!
```

The new message type in the above code works like this: first, it creates an object type by mapping over the keys of `Person` and constructing an object for each one; this sub-object is the same shape as your original `Message` type, but uses the specific key and corresponding type for that key. These sub-object are contained in the top-level object by the keys, so the object is then indexed by the keys to create a union. You can explore it in the playground.

As a "bonus", this new type properly typechecks the *creation* of messages.

With this new type, TS can now narrow the union of `Message` when `msg` is created, allowing it to give `msg` the actual more-concrete type of `{ src: "name"; value: string }`. As TS now knows what the key is, the assignment succeeds. **However, this is only the case if it is created directly like this. A function return, etc., will not work.** For example:

```js
function getMessage(): Message2 {
  return {} as Message2
}

const newMsg2 = getMessage()

person[newMsg2.src] = newMsg2.value // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/Navknm)

So, on to Part 2.

### Solution, Part 2

At this point, your question is very, very similar to ["Assert a value type is the same at both sides of the assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75870887/15261914).

But as your case is *slightly* different, and you need the earlier steps first, I will post this answer anyway.

To quote [@jcalz's answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75879314/15261914):

> TypeScript can't handle "correlated union" types in which a single block of code is checked multiple types for each member of a union. This issue is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The workaround is to use a generic callback function to let TypeScript know that everything is alright.

First, we need to rework the types a little to maintain the correlation between properties. In this case, that is as simple as splitting up the creation of the `Message` type:

```js
type MessageBase = {
  [key in keyof Person]: { src: key; value: Person[key] }
}
type Message = MessageBase[keyof Person]

// `Message` is as before, but `MessageBase` is the following:
type MessageBaseExpanded = {
  name: {
    src: "name";
    value: string;
  };
  age: {
    src: "age";
    value: number;
  };
}
```

This new `MessageBase` type allows us to use a key to get a correlated key and value type. We can then create a "callback" function that uses generics to show TypeScript the correlation:

```js
const performAssignment = <Src extends keyof MessageBase>(message: MessageBase[Src]) => {
  person[message.src] = message.value
}

performAssignment(newMsg)
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0zArw)