# Is there a cleaner way to update the value of **keyof T** on the go?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to copy property values from a source `S` to a target `T`. After programmatically checking that the field exists, I want TS to let me access it, but won't:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    src/util/Copy.ts:18:18 - error TS2536: Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'S'.

    18           return source[field] === target[field];
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/util/Copy.ts:33:11 - error TS2536: Type 'keyof S' cannot be used to index type 'T'.

    33           match[field] = source[field];
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I could make source extend from target to only accept fields that are in both types. But my utility method should handle even completely different types. Here's the code that fails

```
export function copyFieldsWhenMatching<S extends object, T extends object>(
  sourceArray: S[],
  targetArray: T[],
  equalFields: (keyof T)[],
  fieldsToCopy: (keyof S)[],
  allowMultipleOccurrences: boolean
): T[] {
  const toReturn = [...targetArray];

  for (const source of sourceArray) {
    // Find matches based on equalFields
    const matches = toReturn.filter((target) => {
      return equalFields.every((field) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(field) && target.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
          return source[field] === target[field];
        }
        return true; // Property doesn't exist in either source or target; continue matching.
      });
    });

    if (!allowMultipleOccurrences && matches.length > 1) {
      throw new DuplicateMatchesError(
        "More than one match found for the source object.",
        matches
      );
    } else if (matches.length >= 1 || allowMultipleOccurrences) {
      // Copy fields from source to matches
      for (const match of matches) {
        for (const field of fieldsToCopy) {
          match[field] = source[field];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

And this is how I hacked it to pass through (casting target to source and inversely just to get through). So that brought me to the question in the title:

> Is there a cleaner way to update the value of **keyof T** on the go?

```
import { DuplicateMatchesError } from "../errors";

export function copyFieldsWhenMatching<S extends object, T extends object>(
  sourceArray: S[],
  targetArray: T[],
  equalFields: (keyof T)[],
  fieldsToCopy: (keyof S)[],
  allowMultipleOccurrences: boolean,
): T[] {
  const toReturn = [...targetArray];

  for (const source of sourceArray) {
    // Find matches based on equalFields
    const matches = toReturn.filter((target) => {
      return equalFields.every((field) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(field) && target.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
          return (
            // dirty assertion to hack TS
            (source as unknown as T)[field] ===
            target[field]
          );
        }
        return true; // Property doesn't exist in either source or target; continue matching.
      });
    });

    if (!allowMultipleOccurrences && matches.length > 1) {
      throw new DuplicateMatchesError(
        "More than one match found for the source object.",
        matches,
      );
    } else if (matches.length >= 1 || allowMultipleOccurrences) {
      // Copy fields from source to matches
      for (const match of matches) {
        for (const field of fieldsToCopy) {
          // dirty assertion to hack TS
          (match as unknown as S)[field] = source[field];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is related to ["Assert a value type is the same at both sides of the assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75870887/15261914)?

Comment: That answer knows the types in advance, I'm not sure how I could benefit from it.

Comment: The `hasOwnProperty` part is an issue because `hasOwnProperty` is not a typeguard; there's no way for TS to know that the field exists on `source`. This can be fixed using a simple utility function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hoping to achieve by creating the `toReturn` array. You never modify it, so a copy is unnecessary. If you were hoping to prevent changes to the _objects in_ the original array, then you will need more than a shallow copy.

Comment: Maybe I've missed something, but I don't see how the `match` object can be known to definitely have the properties in `fieldsToCopy`. Each of the `match` objects are elements of the `matches` array, which is a subset of `targetArray`. This subset is in no way linked with the presence of the properties listed in `fieldsToCopy`. As it seems that you are trying to _add_a new property, you will likely need to cast `match` to have that property.

Comment: source.hasOwnProperty(field) shows that source (type S) has a field from target (type T). 
equalFields is defined as (keyof T)[]
I'd like to update the type of equalFields (add a property or eventually cast it to a new type) so that it includes this key of (T)arget. 
The idea is to access it in a cleaner way than casting S to T basically by doing (source as unknown as T): which is a dirty way to make the compiler happy, but that is absolutely not true

Comment: To be more precise in my words:
I'd like to update the type of 'equalFields' by adding it the property 'field' that we just verified exists, so that we can call source[field] without casting it to a type that it is not: Target.

Comment: If you are talking about the first of the two errors, that is a trivial issue: instead of using `hasOwnProperty()` directly, use a type guard the uses it internally: `function hasOwnProperty<O extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: O,
  key: K
): obj is O & Record<K, unknown> {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
}`. E.g., `if (hasOwnProperty(source, field) && hasOwnProperty(target, field))`. Then TS will know that the source and target do have those fields.

Comment: Although you don't actually need to check the target, as the keys in `equalFields` are statically guaranteed to be properties of of the target type.

Comment: You're right, I don' t need to check the target, I was too busy trying to solve that question. About your other comment, I tried that, it doesn't work as the type of source didn't change: the compiler doesn't know I checked that the field exists, he is not following the conversation :-)

Comment: It seems to work for me? https://tsplay.dev/mbyKEN

Comment: You are right! I'm new to TS, I didn't know of the existence of a return type like obj is O & Record<K, unknown>. That's exactly what I was searching for. Could you please answer with that so that I can mark your answer and let others benefit from it.
Thanks,

Comment: So, is that all that you want? I can write up an answer, then. Can I ignore your second issue? (type of `match` in `for (const field of fieldsToCopy) { match[field] = source[field]; }`) I don't _think_ it's part of your question (given the title, comments, etc.), and I don't see how it can be solved simply, given what I've said about the correlation, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Yes the second part allows a field not in the type to be added, so it's not even in the requirements  of the function to stick to types. Thanks for the answer

Comment: You could make the return type `(T & Partial<Pick<S, SKeys>>)[]` (where `SKeys` is a new generic parameter for the `keyof S`), to state that the returned objects might have any of the copied properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (source.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
  return source[field] === target[field];
}
```

In this code from your example, you are using `hasOwnProperty()` to check if `source` has the property. However, `hasOwnProperty()` does not narrow its target, so TS doesn't narrow `source` to include the property specified by `field`.

To work around this, you can create a *user-defined type guard* that calls `hasOwnProperty()` and narrows the target object.

TypeScript narrows types of variables in some cases, such as when using `typeof`. By using a return type called a [*type predicate*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), we can create *functions* that narrow the type of their input. These are called *user-defined type guards*.

Here's one for `hasOwnProperty()`:

```
function hasOwnProperty<O extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: O,
  key: K,
): obj is O & Record<K, unknown> {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if (hasOwnProperty(source, field)) {
  return source[field] === target[field]
}
```

Note: This is "meant" to be used with string keys. Since `field` is typed as `keyof T`, it actually types `source` as being of type `S & Record<keyof T, unknown>` (i.e., having all the properties of `T`). However, since simply use the same variable (`field`) to index `source`, it's okay. But be careful if you do more.

Here's that put into your code: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcDyB3MAFAJzgAcBTAqATwB5NFSAPKUsAE3UTgCMArU6ADSIA0vSYt2iQiXJVhpSgD4AFAChEnXgC5EmAesQBrBTuH6AlDu49EMDnQBkiAEr84BVtTOJwhsHFxFRABvAwJSKBACJExefigAOmIiKDgqMgS0LFxpMgpKBIhUABti5WshY0pzVQBfVVVGYncoRFBIWARECBJKADEYUmL2AHVkFgBZVCgIZBgwAHNqAGUxZjYOa3ihABU1iU246BUDdDgoiFIAQQICVEodZYBtAF19DShUAgWIm7uHxA7V7vegARxAJQGQ3YOmUVTgwEB5mBBmAg2G6B2cAAwr1YfDEctkW8DCVigEJiBirBiMVSJgIBAouFIKR0DouHA4HTUGALDogS8QgYemB0K1Uq5ItFEABeRBPBJKz7fX63e4vBoaYDuRDKUXixBnC6kTiI40ES5-e7mYUaDQAegdiAGbEQAFtprM2YguBhSKxOEhSODIej2AYNAbWp6ZuMOPLJREomAEmjqeRlMoVT8oLbZUFQvb7eFpcHQ8UoRiEqQAG7kShZtHQ-OFyPFxBOwEACQAkst28WYIjlFkcPgiHkqMoLZchM3huZbUWO8XSymjedLaQngvWELZYfEDmIrvw5rVxp6pfEOuZVACCBTV3crJKIhWHA2WAAOStRh2K08z0DAUDjAQm4mpwEEnlAADc3QILAYBPh6XpzIsCSDogtQ1MWuFavaw56gAhGSFJUjSdIMkytwsJcHAOE4sbeugCR0osYGIEEACMy7YWBRDYIgYCkMJAAiIC0jARTMFMcZsgAorc7hqDeABEEzuKaYG8kGposcgbTnG6OoweMkHbpofDQAk6kgquhlsg59p4fatT0MU6CmsRyhOWxHELFxijyjxiAAD7hYg5HYJS1IwLS9KMsy9Fsvxq5drixDvnuHDAEQ7qWZcx5wGhCnoNhZl6tGZWzGatXxull5VfqCCGnu9W5ViWXVHaN4NWe0IHkVO57hel7Xh2k1XgY9RhMm95wFKKZ1EAA).

---

For more info on type guards, there's the [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and the excellent [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard) by [basarat](https://github.com/basarat).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to cast all arrays to `(S & T)[]`

```
export function copyFieldsWhenMatching<S extends object, T extends object>(
  sourceArray: S[],
  targetArray: T[],
  equalFields: (keyof T)[],
  fieldsToCopy: (keyof S)[],
  allowMultipleOccurrences: boolean,
): T[] {
  const toReturn = [...targetArray] as (S & T)[];

  for (const source of (sourceArray as (S & T)[])) {
    // Find matches based on equalFields
    const matches = toReturn.filter((target) => {
      return equalFields.every((field) => {
        if (Object.hasOwn(source, field) && Object.hasOwn(target, field)) {
          return source[field] === target[field]
        }
        return true; // Property doesn't exist in either source or target; continue matching.
      });
    });

    if (!allowMultipleOccurrences && matches.length > 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "More than one match found for the source object.",
        { cause: matches },
      );
    }
    if (matches.length === 1 || matches.length > 1 && allowMultipleOccurrences) {
      // Copy fields from source to matches
      for (const match of matches) {
        for (const field of fieldsToCopy) {
          match[field] = source[field];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: This would be worse, from a clean code perspective: as it will make a union of types instead of using only the necessary minimum to make things work